# Creating SharedPreferences object inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, static, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm developing small application for my class mates, which is adjustable timetable. It uses Fragments to display each day of week as a nice, finger-swipable UI:

[image]

In SettingsActivity.class there are preferences (defined in xml), which automatically store settings in SharedPreferences. The problem is that class, in which Fragment is defined, is static. I cannot use there non-static method reference, like that one:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Through reading documentation on developer.android.com and googling for help, I discovered that to use SharedPreferences created by SettingsActivity.class, I have to use [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html), like that:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Now it doesn't show me the error about non-static reference, but I don't know how to refer SettingsActivity.class in getDefaultSharedPreferences argument, because I'm in Fragment static class, so I cannot use "this".

I have also tried to create SharedPreference object outside of the static class. However, all uses of that object complain that "non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context".

It's important for me to use SharedPreferences there, because later I'm going to implement lessons (TextViews) color changing according to an hour, and that is also toggle-able in Settings.

Here is the code of that fragment class:

```
public static class Dzien extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Dzien() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView lekcja1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja1);
        TextView lekcja2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja2);
        TextView lekcja3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja3);
        TextView lekcja4 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja4);
        TextView lekcja5 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja5);
        TextView lekcja6 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja6);
        TextView lekcja7 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja7);
        TextView lekcja8 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja8);
        TextView lekcja9 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja9);


        //Here is where I try to create SharedPreference object
        SharedPreferences settings =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1: { // Poniedziałek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.wos));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.gw));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.his));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.pp));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 1) {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
                } else {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 2: { // Wtorek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.pp));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.rel));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 2) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.ros));
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.ros));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 3: { // Sroda
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.his));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.rel));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 1) {
                    lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.niem));
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.niem));
                } else {
                    lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 4: { // Czwartek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.fiz));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.wok));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.geo));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.chem));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 2) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
                } else if (((settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 2)) && ((settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) != 3))) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brakpre));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 3) {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.por));
                    lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.por));
                }
                break;
            }
            case 5: { // Piątek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.bio));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.edb));
                if (settings.getBoolean(WDZ, false)) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.wdz));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }


        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm using Android Studio IDE.

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref",0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

To get `SharedPreferences` by this method you must pass `Context` object. So you can pass your `Activity` in this case, because `Fragment` has method to get parent `Activity` and `Activity` is extended class from `Context`. Code looks like this :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just Change to this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hung up for several days trying to get the sharepreferences keys stored by my app.   I found this tech note about viewing stored xml sharepref stored on emulator.

http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-shared-preferences-in-android/28370

this gave me the answer as to what I was doing wrong.  The file name default for SharePref seems to be MainActivity.xml.   So below code works.  referencing

private static String filename = "MainActivity";
pref = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0); // new 8/27/14 test