# App force closes when leaving SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android, crash, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

It's my second question after that one (already answered): [Creating SharedPreferences object inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469893/creating-sharedpreferences-object-inside-fragment/17470168?noredirect=1#17470168) .

After figuring out how create SharedPreferences object inside static Fragment class, I've started using it to retrieve values of user settings from SettingsActivity to set TextEdits values. App compiles without errors and starts nicely on emulator, displaying default values (I haven't entered settings yet). Settings open without any problems. However, when I click "up" on ActionBar, app hangs and force closes. After that I'm unable to open it - it force closes all the time until clearing app data.

It looks like after first app open SharedPreference methods in Fragment static class set default data (as they should if they find null) and after entering settings and going back with use of "up" (I haven't changed any value, just left default as defined in preferences xml), app saves that default values into SharedPreferences, then tries to retrieve it to set TextEdits in Fragments. And there is where it closes.

The strange thing is that when I "turn off" all ifs in switch cases inside static Fragment class (public static class Dzien extends Fragment) with use of /* */ comments, app works, enters, leaves Settings and it's possible to swipe through all Fragments without crashing. Even more strange is that "turning on" if in the last case 5...:

```
case 5: { // Piątek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.bio));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.edb));
                if (settings.getBoolean(WDZ, false)) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.wdz));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
```

...doesn't make the Settings crash while leaving them and going to 5th Fragment (where a WDZ is used). I can switch WDZ checkbox and it reflects it's state in the corresponding Fragment.

I have no idea what may cause the crashes, because if blocks in case 1, 2, 3 and 4 are correct - the only difference is that they use getInt() instead getBoolean(). Still, after navigating to corresponding Fragment, app crashes.

Here are the sources:

MainActivity.class (Fragment class in on the bottom)

```
package pl.konpon96.planlekcji;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "app_preferences";

//public static final String GRUPA_ANGIELSKI = "grupa_angielski_list";
public static final String GRUPA_JEZYKOWA = "grupa_jezykowa_list";
public static final String GRUPA_INFORMATYKA = "grupa_informatyka_list";
public static final String WDZ = "wdz_checkbox";
//public static final String PODSWIETLANIE_LEKCJI = "podswietlanie_lekcji_checkboxs";

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //Ustawianie domyślnej zakładki w zależności od dnia

    Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();

    switch (timeNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.TUESDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.THURSDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.FRIDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.SATURDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            Toast sobotaToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Jest sobota - nie ma zajęć", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            sobotaToast.show();
            break;
        }
        case Calendar.SUNDAY: {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            Toast niedzielaToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Jest niedziela - nie ma zajęć", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            niedzielaToast.show();
            break;
        }


    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_dzwonki: {
            Intent dzwonkiActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DzwonkiActivity.class);
            startActivity(dzwonkiActivity);
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new Dzien();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Dzien.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_pon).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_wt).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_sr).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_czw).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_pt).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
/*
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
*/
public static class Dzien extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Dzien() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView lekcja1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja1);
        TextView lekcja2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja2);
        TextView lekcja3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja3);
        TextView lekcja4 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja4);
        TextView lekcja5 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja5);
        TextView lekcja6 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja6);
        TextView lekcja7 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja7);
        TextView lekcja8 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja8);
        TextView lekcja9 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lekcja9);

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1: { // Poniedziałek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.wos));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.gw));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.his));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.pp));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 1) {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
                } else {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 2: { // Wtorek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.pp));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.rel));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 2) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.ros));
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.ros));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 3: { // Sroda
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.his));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.wf));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.rel));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 1) {
                    lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.niem));
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.niem));
                } else {
                    lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }
            case 4: { // Czwartek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.fiz));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.wok));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.geo));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.ang));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.chem));
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 2) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
                } else if (((settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 2)) && ((settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) != 3))) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brakpre));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_JEZYKOWA, 1) == 3) {
                    lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.por));
                    lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.por));
                }
                break;
            }
            case 5: { // Piątek
                lekcja1.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja2.setText(getString(R.string.mat));
                lekcja3.setText(getString(R.string.bio));
                lekcja4.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja5.setText(getString(R.string.pol));
                lekcja6.setText(getString(R.string.edb));
                if (settings.getBoolean(WDZ, false)) {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.wdz));
                } else {
                    lekcja7.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                }
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                lekcja9.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
                break;
            }


        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

SettingsActivity.class - there is a little mess after removing pre-compiled preference fragments - I'm using deprecated API cause it isn't going to use tablet UI.

```
package pl.konpon96.planlekcji;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
 * handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
 * settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
 * the list of settings.
 * <p/>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("grupa_angielski_list"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("grupa_jezykowa_list"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("grupa_informatyka_list"));
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() { // Przycisk UP na ActionBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // Akcja użytkownika - przycisk UP
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            // TODO: If Settings has multiple levels, Up should navigate up
            // that hierarchy.
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * Shows the simplified settings UI if the device configuration if the
 * device configuration dictates that a simplified, single-pane UI should be
 * shown.
 */

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
 * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
 * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
 * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
 * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
 */
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}

/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

}
```

Preferences pref_general.xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_header_personalizacja">

    <ListPreference
            android:key="grupa_jezykowa_list"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_grupa_jezykowa"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/pref_grupa_jezykowa_list_titles"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_grupa_jezykowa_values"
            android:negativeButtonText="@null"
            android:positiveButtonText="@null"/>


    <ListPreference
            android:key="grupa_angielski_list"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_grupa_angielski"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/pref_grupa_angielski_list_titles"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_grupa_angielski_values"
            android:negativeButtonText="@null"
            android:positiveButtonText="@null"/>

    <ListPreference
            android:key="grupa_informatyka_list"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_grupa_informatyka"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/pref_grupa_informatyka_list_titles"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_grupa_informatyka_values"
            android:negativeButtonText="@null"
            android:positiveButtonText="@null"/>

    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="wdz_checkbox"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_wdz"
            android:summary="@string/pref_description_wdz"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

And here is the logcat of emulator after opening app first time, entering settings then going back:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6200994/logcat.txt

Comment: zapomniałeś o najważniejszym ... gdzie są logi z logcat ? a inna rzecz ... dane przechowywane w kodzie? a jak będziesz chciał szybko zmienić?

Comment: Do you have a Logcat?

Comment: @Selvin

To bardzo wczesna wersja, daleka od gotowej. Na razie muszę mieć przygotowane wszystkie inne narzędzia, jak np SharedPreferences. Później zajmę się rozłożeniem wyświetlania tekstów na oddzielną klasę aby poprawić czytelność i przeniesieniem całego planu do xml albo SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's all clear now. SharedPreferences saved automatically by SettingsActivity are of String type, so there should be used getString() instead of getInt(). What's more, if there are two strings to compare, there should be used .equal() method instead of == operator.

For example...:

```
if (settings.getInt(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, 1) == 1) {
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
            } else {
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
            }
```

...should be:

```
if (settings.getString(GRUPA_INFORMATYKA, "1").equals("1")) {
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.inf));
            } else {
                lekcja8.setText(getString(R.string.brak));
            }
```

Thanks for people who reminded me about the logcat. :)